# How to avoid repeating code within togglers using HOC in react

Tags: reactjs, togglebutton, high-order-component

I tried to implement an HOC in react in order to avoid code repetition, so I created 2 buttons to toggle the components state, following my code:

Clickbtn.js:

```
export default class Card extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = {
      starred: true
    }
    this.toggleStar = this.toggleStar.bind(this);
  }
  toggleStar() {
    this.setState({ starred: !this.state.starred })
  }
  render() {
    const { starred } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <h3>My sweet Repo</h3>
        <p>My sweet description</p>
        <button onClick={this.toggleStar}>{starred ? "OK" : "NOK"}</button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Hideshow.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Hideshow extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.toggleShow = this.toggleShow.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      show: true
    };
  }
  
  toggleShow() {
    this.setState({ show: !this.state.show })
  }

  render() {
    const { show } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.toggleShow}>Menu</button>
        { show && <nav style={{ listStyleType: 'none' }}>
         <a href="/#">Home</a>
         <a href="/#">Profile</a>
         <a href="/#">About</a>
        </nav>}
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

HOC.js:

```
function withToggler(Component) {
  return class extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
         on: true
      };
    }

    toggler = () => {
      this.setState({ on: !this.state.on });
    };

    render() {
      const { on } = this.state;
      const { component , ...props } = this.props;
      return (
        <Component
          on={on}
          toggler={this.toggler}
          {...props}
        />
      );
    }
  };
}

export default withToggler;
```

However, I tried several ways to implement the HOC in my Clickbtn.js and Hideshow.js but I didn't yet figure out how to do that. I know that this part of the code is repeated:

```
 constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = {
      starred: true
    }
    this.toggleStar = this.toggleStar.bind(this);
  }
  toggleStar() {
    this.setState({ starred: !this.state.starred })
  }
```

So my question is how to implement HOC to avoid this code repetition?

Comment: What is the problem with the HOC you have given in the question ? It should work I think.

Comment: I edited my question in order to make it clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use on and toggler props from withToggler to avoid repetition.

```js
class Card extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super()

    this.toggleStar = this.props.toggler;
  }

  render() {
    const starred  = this.props.on;
    return ( <
      div >
      <
      h3 > My sweet Repo < /h3> <
      p > My sweet description < /p> <
      button onClick = {
        this.toggleStar
      } > {
        starred ? "OK" : "NOK"
      } < /button> <
      /div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: I have no errors in my console, but the component state didn't change whenever I click on

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/vibrant-surf-97b2hn?file=/src/withToggler.js
I tried the demo the button is changing

Comment: Thank you that works, but I didnt why the "starred" variable when it is declared as object destructor doesn't work ( const { starred } = this.props.on). However, if it is declared as a normal variable it works ( const starred = this.props.on)

Comment: props.on is the boolean property from parent. The const { starred } = this.props.on) works if the on is a object with starred key.